# Is it wise to store properties of a class in an ArrayList rather than using fields?

Tags: java, arrays, list, class, properties

Can I store text from different text fields in an `ArrayList` and store it into my `Customer` property in the `Booking` class. Right now it's reading every text field and saving them into different properties.

```
private String flighttime;
private String flightlocation;
private String flightfee;
private boolean car;
private boolean insurance;
private Customer customer;

private void savebookingButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
        Booking customerbooking = new Booking();
        Customer cust = null;

        try {
            if (custnameTF.getText().equals("")) {
                throw new EmptyField("Please Insert Customer");
            } else {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Bookings/" + custidTF.getText() + ".txt");
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

                cust.setPersonName((custnameTF.getText()));
                cust.setPersonSurname((custsurnameTF.getText()));
                cust.setPersonID((custidTF.getText()));
                cust.setConsultantname(consnameTF.getText());
                cust.setConsultantsurname((conssurnameTF.getText()));
                cust.setConsulid(considTF.getText());
                customerbooking.setFlightlocation(locationCB.getSelectedItem().toString());
                customerbooking.setFlighttime(timeCB.getSelectedItem().toString());
                customerbooking.setFlightfee(feeCB.getSelectedItem().toString());
                customerbooking.setCar(carRB.isSelected());
                customerbooking.setInsurance(insuranceRB.isSelected());

                oos.writeObject(customerbooking);
                oos.close();
                fos.close();

                custnameTF.setText("");
                custsurnameTF.setText("");
                custidTF.setText("");
                considTF.setText("");
                consnameTF.setText("");
                conssurnameTF.setText("");
                locationCB.setSelectedItem("");
                timeCB.setSelectedItem("");
                feeCB.setSelectedItem("");
```

Comment: You are rather looking for a `HashMap` instead of an `ArrayList` to be able to identify the the values better. But what is the bad thing about 6 single variables in the `Booking` class?

Comment: Of course you can - but the question is: is it wise? I'd say no since you introduce a source for bugs and lose information (e.g. field name etc.).

Comment: Java is not Javascript. Please use the proper content for both tags and language label.

Comment: Since I didn't use Swing in a while I'm no expert here but IIRC you could use bean introspection to bind properties to ui components, i.e. you'd provide the component with a property name and a bean and the framework would handle the transfer between the two - the keywords for your search would be "java data binding" and probably "swing" or "javafx" as well.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "no".

Dealing with property values in a list with an implicit order for mapping to your data object is brittle.

However, it is sometimes very useful to manage properties of objects in aggregate using something like property change support or beans, though an `ArrayList` is a poor choice of a data structure versus at least a `Map` of property-name to value or a more thorough data-binding solution such as typed properties to represent keys, pairs to map keys to values, and data structures to store current values and mutations.

There is overhead somewhere that must match your property names to accessors and mutators of your data object classes. This may be done using a library such as for databinding or some custom solution of property-to-field mapping or perhaps storing your state in a `Map` within the data objects. There are complex ways to do this while maintaining type-safety, but many solutions deal with properties as `String` and values as `Object` and throw away the type information and type checks, so that would be one hurdle to implementing it well.

Another related part of your question ought to be change management and only writing things that changed. For example, if one of your fields changes, you don't need to overwrite all the other fields of your data object but only the ones that are different. Whether you move to a property-based update model or stick with explicit use of accessors and mutators, you ought to investigate this also. If going with the property-based approach where you can deal with properties in aggregate or via delegation to handlers, the code in your UI should evaporate and be passed to libraries which could deal with type-safety, change management, firing subsequent change events, and other related concerns.